# Preciso fazer um select de receitas e seus respectivos ingredientes, sem repetir os outros campos da receita

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

**Tabela Receita**

---------------------
id
nome
modo de preparo
categoria

**Tabela Ingrediente**

--------------------------
id
nome

**Tabela Ingrediente_receita**

--------------------------------------
id
id_receita
id_ingrediente

Quero fazer um select que traga as receitas com seus respectivos ingredientes conforme os ingredientes que eu informar.

Ex: select das receitas que possuem farinha, ovo e açucar (Quero que traga receitas que possuem só esses 3 ingredientes, se a receita tiver mais algum ingrediente, não quero que apareça)

Supondo que um bolo de cenoura só tenha esses 3 ingredientes

Nao quero que traga assim:

1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | farinha
1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | ovo
1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | açucar

Quero que traga assim (Tudo na mesma linha):

1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | farinha | ovo | açucar

Banco de dados: Mysql

Podem me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Oq vc ja tem de codigo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos precisar de 2 parâmetros, os id's dos ingredientes que vamos procurar e a quantidade de ingredientes que estão sendo procurados. Aí faremos da seguinte maneira:

Estrutura de tabelas teste:

```
CREATE TABLE receita(id int, nome varchar(20), preparo varchar(20), categoria int);
CREATE TABLE ingrediente(id int, nome varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE ingrediente_receita(id int, id_receita int, id_ingrediente int);

INSERT INTO receita VALUES(1,'bolo','teste',1);

INSERT INTO ingrediente values(1, 'farinha'),(2,'açucar'),(3,'ovo');

insert into ingrediente_receita VALUES(1,1,1);
insert into ingrediente_receita VALUES(1,1,3);
```

não criei relacionamento pois é apenas para referenciar os campos ao campo da consulta para ficar claro, sendo assim, segue a consulta:

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.preparo,
    r.categoria,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.nome SEPARATOR ' | ') AS ingrediente
FROM receita r
INNER JOIN ingrediente_receita ir
ON ir.id_receita = r.id
INNER JOIN ingrediente i
ON i.id = ir.id_ingrediente
WHERE r.id IN(
SELECT
    r.id
FROM receita r
INNER JOIN ingrediente_receita ir
ON ir.id_receita = r.id
INNER JOIN ingrediente i
ON i.id = ir.id_ingrediente
WHERE ir.id_ingrediente IN(1,3)[id_ingredientes]
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ingrediente_receita WHERE id_receita = r.id) = 2[qtd_ingredientes])
```

no parâmetro [id_ingredientes] vamos passar os id's separados por ',', e no paramêtro [qtd_ingredientes] vamos passar a quantidade de ingredientes.

o retorno da consulta com os parâmetros acima será este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí para futuro testes pode ir trocando os id's e as quantidades, exemplo IN(1,2) por mais que ele encontre a farinha não irá retornar pois estamos procurando alguma receita que tenha 2 ingredientes[qtd_ingredientes] e nesse retorno ele traria apenas 1 linha representando a farinha.

Comment: arllondias tentei fazer o que voce passou, porém mesmo informando a quantidade de ingredientes 2, ele trouxe a receita e mostrou os 3 ingredientes que ela possui.

Sou novo no fórum, consigo inserir uma imagem aqui?

Comment: Quantos parâmetros você enviou dentro do IN e qual o valor colocou em quantidade, não é para retornar não, se quiser mande no meu e-mail a imagem, e tento auxiliar por lá. arllon.dias05@gmail.com

Comment: colooquei 2 parâmetros no IN e a quantidade 2, mas mesmo assim ele retornou a receita e mostrou os 3 ingrdientes que ela possui, mandei a imagem no seu email, obrigado.

Comment: deu certo, obrigado arllon

Comment: Tranquilo, por nada.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor que ja fez sua busca e deu um fetch array nela, ficando com o resultado:

1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | farinha

1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | ovo

1| Bolo de cenoura | modo de preparo: blablabla | Categoria: Doces | açucar

```
$rs = [
   0 => [
      'id' => '1',
      'receita' => 'bolo de cenoura',
      'modo' => 'bla bla bla',
      'categoria' => 'doces',
      'ingrediente' => 'farinha'
   ],
   1 => [
      'id' => '2',
      'receita' => 'bolo de cenoura',
      'modo' => 'bla bla bla',
      'categoria' => 'doces',
      'ingrediente' => 'açucar'
   ],
   2 => [
      'id' => '3',
      'receita' => 'bolo de cenoura',
      'modo' => 'bla bla bla',
      'categoria' => 'doces',
      'ingrediente' => 'ovo'
   ]
]
```

O que você vai fazer é selecionar uam coluna, no caso `'ingredientes'`, e implodir os dados dessa `array` em uma `string`:

```
$ingredientes = array_column($rs, 'ingrediente');
$lista_ingredientes = implode(',', $ingredientes);
echo $lista_ingredientes; //farinha,açucar,ovo
```

Exemplo funcional no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/eCvs0i)

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer uma query mais elaborada pra trazer tudo apenas uma vez ?